# Create and compare snapshots of a schema definition

Tags: database, oracle

I want to take a snapshot of all table, view and procedure **definitions**, and diff this snapshot against another version of the same schema. (By *snapshot* I mean the schema definition stored in some text file.)
I am not interested in procedure bodies, only in what is relevant to my DAOs. (Maybe you could call that a schema interface...?)
Is there a one-command way of creating such snapshot for an Oracle schema?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Oracle SQL Developer** "Database Diff" to do this. You can select the two Oracle schemas to be compared and it produces all the differences

The good thing about this tool is that it allows you to select what to consider when differences are produced, and, then, you have the option of only comparing package specs

Comment: That sounds almost perfect, only that I need to compare current state of the schema with an older snapshot... I have just realized maybe the word "snapshot" is misleading. By that I mean a text file with table/view definitions and procedure signatures.

Comment: Maybe then you can use the same tool to generate scripts (for selective objects) and have that version controlled. You can compare the different versions using any text compare tool

Comment: yes, that is my alternative approach... currently in progress